# Use static data initializers inline

Tags: c++, boost, initializer, multiprecision

I have found this section in the [`cpp_dec_float`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp) source file:

```
struct initializer
  {
     initializer()
     {
        cpp_dec_float<Digits10, ExponentType, Allocator>::nan();
        cpp_dec_float<Digits10, ExponentType, Allocator>::inf();
        (cpp_dec_float<Digits10, ExponentType, Allocator>::min)();
        (cpp_dec_float<Digits10, ExponentType, Allocator>::max)();
        cpp_dec_float<Digits10, ExponentType, Allocator>::zero();
        cpp_dec_float<Digits10, ExponentType, Allocator>::one();
        cpp_dec_float<Digits10, ExponentType, Allocator>::two();
        cpp_dec_float<Digits10, ExponentType, Allocator>::half();
        cpp_dec_float<Digits10, ExponentType, Allocator>::double_min();
        cpp_dec_float<Digits10, ExponentType, Allocator>::double_max();
        cpp_dec_float<Digits10, ExponentType, Allocator>::long_double_max();
        cpp_dec_float<Digits10, ExponentType, Allocator>::long_double_min();
        cpp_dec_float<Digits10, ExponentType, Allocator>::long_long_max();
        cpp_dec_float<Digits10, ExponentType, Allocator>::long_long_min();
        cpp_dec_float<Digits10, ExponentType, Allocator>::ulong_long_max();
        cpp_dec_float<Digits10, ExponentType, Allocator>::eps();
        cpp_dec_float<Digits10, ExponentType, Allocator>::pow2(0);
     }
     void do_nothing(){}
  };
```

I'd like to use some of those values such as `zero`, `one`, `two`, and `half` rather than declaring global `const` variables.

Is it possible to use those values inline?  If so, how?

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/078d77148aa2f103):

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/number.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;

int main()
{
    typedef mp::number<mp::cpp_dec_float<100>> mp_type;
    mp_type test_num("7.0710678");

    test_num *= mp_type.two();

    std::cout << test_num.str( 0, std::ios_base::scientific ) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::multiprecision::number` repeats its first template argument as a public member type `backend_type`.  So,

```
test_num = test_num * mp_type::backend_type::two();
```